# Using Databricks Connect

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks, azure-databricks

I'd like to edit Databricks notebooks locally using my favorite editor, and then use [Databricks Connect](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-connect/) to run the notebook remotely on a Databricks cluster that I usually access via the web interface.

Unfortunately, after searching the web for a couple days, I can't find detailed documentation on Databricks Connect.

I run `databricks-connect configure`, as suggested on the PyPI page above, but I'm not sure what some of the settings are. Could someone please walk me through this (like where to find these values in the web interface) or provide a link to proper documentation?

I know what some of the settings should be, but I'll include everything that comes up when running `databricks-connect configure`, for completeness and benefit of others.

`Databricks Host` 
`Databricks Token` 
`Cluster ID` (e.g., `0921-001415-jelly628`) 
`Org ID` (Azure-only, see `?o=orgId` in URL) 
`Port` (is it `spark.databricks.service.port` ?)

Also, and I think it's what I'm most interested in, do I need to make any changes in the notebook itself, such as define SparkContext or something? If so, with what configuration?

And how should I run it? After running `databricks-connect configure`, there doesn't seem any "magic" to be happening. When I run `jupyter notebook`, it still runs locally and doesn't seem to know to forward it to a remote cluster.

**Update:**
If you'd like to think of something more concrete, in Databricks' web interface, `dbutils` is a predefined object. How do I refer to it when running a notebook remotely?

Comment: Ideally you want to stick to a single question at a time. This looks like you are asking for a walk-through or tutorial, and SO is not a great source for that. It is unlikley you are going to get much traction here.

Comment: I guess... But if there's a good documentation somewhere, I'd be pretty happy with just a link.

Comment: If I had to choose one question, it would be "Do I need to change anything in the notebook to be able to run it?" I think I could work my way through it from a starting point like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't really how SO works. Basically, this project looks like a thin wrapper around the Azure API, so your starting guess would be that the config refers directly back to that.

Comment: It's currently in private preview so no documents available. You can try going through your Microsoft account manager to get on the preview.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using Databricks on Azure, so I can't look at how it's setup there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had marked another person's reply as the answer, but that reply is gone now for some reason.

For my purposes, the official user guide worked:
https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dev-tools/db-connect.html

Comment: I got deleted for just posting a link 

Comment: That's weird. Your post filled all the missing pieces for me that I was unable find on the web otherwise, including the user guide

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that I have to be the admin to complete this setup? I really hate the notebook editor...

Comment: Right, you need an admin to set the cluster properties. You should be able to do the rest on your own.

Comment: **Update to the above comment:** starting with Databricks Runtime 5.5, the cluster gets configured automatically to be able to accept databricks-connect connections.

Comment: Link in the answer seems to be no longer valid, updated link here https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html

Answer (score 1):

In short you will need to include:

> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

At the start of scripts. Notebooks should convert, but of course magic commands (%run etc) will not work.

More detail is available here on the parts that will not work. https://datathirst.net/blog/2019/3/7/databricks-connect-finally